# CustomError typescript, wrong instance of the error inside the component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, error-handling, next.js

I have a custom Error

```
export class CustomError extends Error{
  constructor(message: string) {
    super(message);
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, CustomError.prototype);
    this.name = "CustomError";
  }
```

and I have a react component with axios req:

```
try {
      axios.post("/api/create", .....
    } catch (error) {
       console.log(error instanceof CustomError); // FALSE ??? 
    }
    setFormIsDisabled(false);
  };
```

and in my service I have func and if something would go wrong I call this error:

```
  
  let error = new CustomError("User exists!")
    console.log(error instanceof CustomError); // true
    throw error
```

And everything would be good but I dont get it why I have wrong instance of the error inside my try catch (instead of CustomError it's Error)?

Comment: In my try I call the function in my service which throw new CustomError("message")

Comment: Isn't `axios.post` asynchronous?  How do you get a synchronous error out of it?  Are you using `await axios.post`?

Comment: And for this service, is it also a client-side service, or is this a server-side service that's throwing `CustomError` and it's on the client that you're catching it and expecting it to be the same kind of error?

Comment: Good question, it's a server-side service that's throwing CustomError, and I'm trying to catch it on the client side, I assume that's impossible?

Comment: Then you'll need to handle the `CustomError` on the server, like maybe returning an appropriate status code in the response. When making the request the client-side will only ever be aware of the response that's returned from `axios.post`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're trying to throw / catch across the network boundary.  But HTTP doesn't know about JavaScript (or Python, or Visual Basic, or any programming language).  So the JavaScript on the server side is *serializing* the error and sending it back as part of the payload of an HTTP error (the 400-599 range of HTTP codes).  Then, on the client, the JavaScript there is turning the HTTP error into a JavaScript error again, but it's a different kind of error.  If you want it to be the same *kind* of error then you need to re-create your `CustomError` on the client:

```js
if (response.code >= 400) {
  if (determineIfResponseIsACustomError(response)) {
    throw new CustomError(extractErrorInformationFrom(response));
  } else {
    // Do other error handling here - this is an example
    throw new Error(`Unhandled HTTP exception: ${response.code}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, thanks for your answer, but I have a problem with this, because if I throw an error inside my service (server-side) there's no way I determine in the client-side is it a CustomError or not?

Comment: You _can_ @klijakub - you just need to have the API Route send back a response that you can interpret properly - e. g. `res.status(409).json({ type: "CustomError", message: "No can do" })` - then on the client you can turn the response into a `CustomError`.